# Batch script to update values in a Tilda separated file

Tags: batch-file

Here is the input file:

```
!~ItemID~RevID~DsetType~DsetName~DsetDesc~FileRef~File~RelationName
DR_QPC_M999~A~PDFA~DR_QPC_M999_A_001~~PDF~.\APR28_Batch1\DR_QPC_M999\A\DR_QPC_M999_A_001.pdf~IMAN_specification
DR_QPC_M999~A~PDFA~DR_QPC_M999_A_001~Imported QPC~PDF~.\APR28_Batch1\DR_QPC_M999\A\DR_QPC_M999_A_001.pdf~IMAN_specification
```

I Wrote this below script to Check the 3rd value and according to that value update the sixth value.

So, the mapping works like this

if 3rd value is PDFA --> update the 3rd value PDFA to R8PDFA
and then check if 6th value is PDF then -->update the 6th value as R8PDFA.

The output I am getting:

```
!~ItemID~RevID~DsetType~DsetName~DsetDesc~FileRef~File~RelationName 
DR_QPC_M999~A~R8PDFA~DR_QPC_M999_A_001~PDF~.\APR28_Batch1\DR_QPC_M999\A\DR_QPC_M999_A_001.pdf~IMAN_specification~ 
DR_QPC_M999~A~R8PDFA~DR_QPC_M999_A_001~Imported QPC~R8PDFA~.\APR28_Batch1\DR_QPC_M999\A\DR_QPC_M999_A_001.pdf~IMAN_specification
```

the problem is for the 2nd line :
if the input value is like:

```
DR_QPC_M999~A~PDFA~DR_QPC_M999_A_001~~PDF~.\APR28_Batch1\DR_QPC_M999\A\DR_QPC_M999_A_001.pdf~IMAN_specification
```

that is if it has two Back to back `~~` like this its not taking it as two separate delimiter. But If I put in the input file like `~ ~` the script is working.

Need a batch script that will solve this issue.

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: treating consecutive delimiters as one is the way `for` behaves. You can't change that. Something like `set "line=!line:,,=, ,!"` (changing two consecutive delimiters to delimiter-space-delimiter) doesn't work for `~`, because it is part of the `set` syntax. I'm afraid the most elegant solution is to let PowerShell do the work.

Comment: for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1-8 delims=~" %%a in ("%file_path%") do(
set "third_value=%%c"
set "sixth_value=%%f"
if "!third_value!"=="PDFA"(
set "third_value=R8PDFA"
if "!sixth_value!"=="PDF" set "sixth_value=R8PDFA"
)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q76161584.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 CALL :process
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:process
:: remove variables starting #
FOR /F "delims==" %%y In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%y="
SET "#line=%line%"
SET /a #index=-1
:nextfield
SET /a #field+=1
SET /a #fieldlength=-1

:nextchar
SET /a #index+=1
SET /a #fieldlength+=1
SET "#char=%line:~0,1%"
SET "line=%line:~1%"
IF "%#char%" neq "~" GOTO nextchar
IF %#field%==3 (
 SET /a #field3end=#index
 SET /a #field3start=#index-#fieldlength
 SET /a #field3length=#fieldlength
)
IF %#field%==6 (
 SET /a #field6end=#index
 SET /a #field6start=#index-#fieldlength
 SET /a #field6length=#fieldlength
 GOTO subs
)
GOTO nextfield

:subs
IF %#field3length% neq 4 GOTO nosubs
CALL SET "test=%%#line:~%#field3start%,4%%"
IF "%test%" neq "PDFA" GOTO nosubs
IF %#field6length% neq 3 GOTO sub3
CALL SET "test=%%#line:~%#field6start%,3%%"
IF "%test%" equ "PDF" CALL SET "#line=%%#line:~0,%#field6start%%%R8PDFA%%#line:~%#field6end%%%"
:sub3
CALL SET "#line=%%#line:~0,%#field3start%%%R8PDFA%%#line:~%#field3end%%%"

:nosubs
ECHO %#line%

GOTO :eof
```

OK - back to basics. With the limited test data available, this process works for me.

Assign each line of data to `%%e` and `line` in turn.

Calculate the start and length of each field by processing `line` character-by-character.

Record the start and length of fields 3 and 6.

Apply the rules for substitution when field 6 has been found.

It's not clear whether the substitution in field 6 is to be done only if the substitution in field 3 happens. I've assumed that it is.

The substitution(s) must then be performed in reverse order as each substitution then affects the start-location of later fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are *a lot* of unespecified details in your problem. For example:

- Can the first field be empty?
- Can the last field be empty?
- Can be more than two adjacent fields empty?
- Can the 4th field (the one after the target field 3) be empty?
- Can the 7th field (the one after the target field 6) be empty?

The code below assume that the answer to all previous questions is: No.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set "header="
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined header (
      set "header=1"
      echo %%a
   ) else (
      call :processLine "%%~a" < NUL
   )
)) > output.txt
goto :EOF


:processLine
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=%~1"
set "i=0"
set "changed3="
:nextField
   set /A i+=1
   set "rest=%line:*~=%"
   if "%rest%" equ "%line%" goto endFields
      if "%rest:~0,1%" neq "~" (
         set "field=!line:%rest%=!"

         if %i% equ 3 if "!field!" equ "PDFA~" (
            set "field=R8PDFA~"
            set "changed3=1"
         )
         if %i% equ 6 if "!field!" equ "PDF~" if defined changed3 (
            set "field=R8PDFA~
         )

         set /P "=!field!"
      ) else (
         set "field=!line:%rest:~1%=!"
         set /P "=!field!"
         set /A i+=1
         set "rest=%rest:~1%"
      )
   set "line=%rest%"
goto nextField
:endFields
echo %line%
exit /B
```

The method consist in eliminate from the beginning of the line until the first `~` character and get the remainder. Then, eliminate this remainder from the line in order to get the first Tilda-delimited field. This process is repeated until all fields are processed.

If the answer to one of the above questions could be Yes, the code should be modified. Some of those points could be implemented in a very simple way, some not...